# Script does not empty trash containing .deb files

Tags: bash, scripts, ubuntu-mate, trash

This script works with any file except .deb files?

Anyone know why?

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home/andy/.local/share/Trash/expunged/ -type f -exec rm {} \;
find /home/andy/.local/share/Trash/files/ -type f -exec rm {} \;
find /home/andy/.local/share/Trash/info/ -type f -exec rm {} \;
find /media/andy/MAXTOR_SDB2/.Trash-1000/files/ -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

Answer (score -1):

Either a permissions issue, or there aren't any .deb files to empty. Not sure why you'd even need a script to empty the trash, unless you're deleting thousands of files an hour, when you can just click "empty trash".